# append to a list doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
>>> l = [1, '+', 2, '']
>>> l
[1, '+', 2, '']
>>> [l[0]]
[1]
>>> l[2:]
[2, '']
>>> l[2:][0]
2
>>> [l[0]].append(l[2:][0])
>>>
```

I was expecting `[1, 2]` from the last line. Why does the expression evaluate to nothing instead?

Comment: Works exactly as documented. Why did you expect differently?

Comment: Note that `l[2:][0]` is just `l[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append()` returns `None`, so no output occurs. Create a new variable, e.g. `result` that holds `[l[0]]`, and then append to that list. Then, output that variable `result` on the REPL, and it should give the desired output.

For example:

```py
>>> l = [1, '+', 2, '']
>>> l
[1, '+', 2, '']
>>> result = [l[0]]
>>> result.append(l[2:][0])
>>> result
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how append works. [Read this documentation to understand more](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) . On quick note append adds item to end of a list.

Now, regarding your question you should make new variable storing `l[0]` and then append the remaining value to it. The code should look like this.

```
>>> l = [1, '+', 2, '']
>>> temp = [l[0]]
>>> temp.append(l[2:][0])
>>> temp
[1,2]
```